# rails check_box always has 0 value

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a form with checkbox. The form is mapped to a model.
According to rails documentation to prevent a problem when checkbox is unclicked and nothing for this field is sent, rails generate hidden field just before the checkbox with 0 as a value.
That's correct.

What is not correct is that after I click the checkbox and submit the form, I can see in the post request that first is sent the value 1 and then value 0 (from hidden field)
And as a result of this, the checkbox has always value 0.

The documentation is correct when it says that parameters extraction gets the last occurrence of any repeated key in the query string, but the order in the post request is not correct ????

I use rails 3.2.11.

**view**

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name), :html => { :method => :put }) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>
    <p><%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %></p>
...
    <div><%= f.label :send_dayplan_info %><br />
    <%= f.check_box :send_dayplan_info %>
    <div><%= f.submit "Update" %></div>
<% end %>
```

**controller**
...

```
def update  
    ...  
    if resource.update_with_password(params[resource_name])  
      ....  
    end  
end
```

**summary**
When I debug and evaluate params[resource_name] it contains always value 0 for send_dayplan_info field.
When I click the checkbox, I can see in firebug post request contains values:
    user[send_dayplan_info]=1
    user[send_dayplan_info]=0

When I unclick the checkbox, I can see in firebug post request contains values:
    user[send_dayplan_info]=0

Below there is form data for clicked checkbox
    utf8:✓
    _method:put
    authenticity_token:....
    user[name]:....
    user[send_dayplan_info]:1
    user[send_dayplan_info]:0

And the source code of the generated html is:
...

```
<div><label for="user_send_dayplan_info">Send dayplan info</label><br />  
<input name="user[send_dayplan_info]" type="hidden" value="0" /><input id="user_send_dayplan_info" name="user[send_dayplan_info]" type="checkbox" value="1" />  
<div><input name="commit" type="submit" value="Update" /></div>
```

Comment: Show us your code, bro.

Comment: I put in the question. Thanks in advance

Comment: 2 questions: **(1)** Does `user[send_dayplan_info]` appear anywhere else in your generated source?  **(2)** Can I see the parameters hash as displayed in your `rails server` terminal after you submit the form?

Comment: Ad 1) no, it appears only with hidden field and checkbox,   Ad 2) 
I use rubymine to debug, and this params I can see in the watch list. Below I copied this hash      ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess (6 element(s))
    'name'="xxxx"
    'email'="yyyyy"
    'password'=""
    'password_confirmation'=""
    'current_password'="xxxx"
    'send_dayplan_info'="0"

Comment: I don't know how RubyMine does it, but I know the `rails server` terminal output will tell you exactly what the server is receiving from your web browser.  You should be seeing two instances of `user[send_dayplan_info]`, with the first=0 and the second=1.  Later values clobber earlier ones, so the 1 should win.  Above in your question, I see you list the 1 *before* the 0, which makes me wonder.

Comment: ok, I try to debug using pure terminal and let you know. This 1 before 0, I see in the firebug console (in chrome or firefox). Of course I don't know if in the same order these fields are parsed by the server, but it seems so. What interesting, I have a different form with checkbox and there everything seems to work properly - so 0 is before 1. I just cannot figure out what's wrong here...

Comment: at the very beginning of the update method I put:
  puts params.inspect  which gave me a result:  
  
  
{"utf8"=>"✓", "_method"=>"put", "authenticity_token"=>"hip5XsRLN6+Qxm97DaYJ+NnKE8+YliyDFN4bko/7wNg=", "user"=>{"name"=>"XXXX", "email"=>"XXXX", "password"=>"", "password_confirmation"=>"", "current_password"=>"123456", "send_dayplan_info"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Update", "action"=>"update", "controller"=>"registrations"}

Comment: Barf.  Is it possible for you to post the full generated html for that page somewhere (like pastebin.com)?  We've got to be missing something.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/nJVv9Nqf    it's valid till tomorrow

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm stuck.  I don't see anything wrong.  Have you tried it in a different browser?  Maybe it's not your code, but the browser that's reading it.  (I'm reaching, now.)

Comment: Yes, I have tried on chrome and firefox. I will deploy my solution to some external hosting and we'll see. I'll let you know. Anyway, thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I found the cause of the problem. I didn't mention that my project uses jquery mobile. Sory for that :( And this makes problem. When I check the source code of generated page (on the server side) everything looks ok. First is hidden and then is checkbox. But then the page is mixed with jquery mobile script (on the client side) and it takes this hidden and put it on the very end of the form. This can be checked using firebug only. So again sory that I didn't mention jquery mobile and now I have to somehow find a workaround for the jq script...

Comment: Nice work, glad you solved it.